# Notation for leads and lags in difference-in-differences

Tags: regression, econometrics, notation, difference-in-difference, sum

I was hoping someone could help clarify a notational discrepancy.

For example, Lord Pischke uses the following sigma notation in two different lecture notes published on the web, yet refers to the limits in disparate ways. The first ([Version 1](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec524/evaluation3.pdf) see page 7) is reproduced below:

$$
y_{ist} = \gamma_s + \lambda_{t} + \sum_{j=-m}^{q}{\beta_{j}} D_{st}(t = k + j) + X_{ist} \delta + \epsilon_{ist}.
$$

The second ([Version 2](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/ec533/did.pdf) see slide 9) is also reproduced below:

$$
y_{ist} = \gamma_s + \lambda_{t} + \sum_{j=-m}^{q}{\beta_{j}} D_{st+j} + \epsilon_{ist}.
$$

The structure is the same. The $k$ in the former equation is the time at which treatment is switched on in state $s$. This formulation can generalize to any number of leads or lags of the treatment variable. Referring to the former equation, Pischke indicates that $m$ is the *lead* and $q$ is the *lag*. While in the latter specification his lecture notes report the opposite, indicating $m$ is the *lag* and $q$ is the *lead*. I believe the latter interpretation is correct. To illustrate, $D_{s,t-1}$ is the treatment variable lagged by one period. I am not sure if this is a mistake on his part.

The impetus for this question stems from another post (see below) where Andy recommended interacting pre-intervention time dummies with a treatment indicator. Negative subscripts could be used to indicate months *leading up to a policy change*, and do not necessary indicate "lags" in the traditional sense.

For example, assuming we have an arbitrary number of $k$ periods *before* some policy change, then $\sum_{t=-k}^{0}{\beta_{t}}$ is a parsimonious way of indicating we want to estimate separate dummies for each time period *approaching the baseline* (i.e., $t = 0$).

Questions:

1. Is the interpretive discrepancy between the two equations an oversight on Pischke's part?
2. Is a negative in the lower limit of a summation always indicative of a lag, or could it be used to denote pre-period time dummies?

[Difference in Difference method: how to test for assumption of common trend between treatment and control group?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160359/difference-in-difference-method-how-to-test-for-assumption-of-common-trend-betw/160361#160361)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ is the lag (post-treatment effects) and $q$ is the lead (anticipatory effects) in the Mostly Harmless book. I have always found this lead/lag terminology unnatural, but lead makes sense if you think of it as a kind of leading indicator. Lag makes sense if you think of the effect lagging treatment.

The time dummies are the $\lambda$s. You can think of D as the set of  "ever treated" x time dummies interactions (though possibly not all the possible interactions).

Comment: It does seem unnatural. I recently wanted to demonstrate a pre-specification test. I used a summation to parsimonious show the interaction of treatment, $T_{s}$, with the pre-period dummies. See the following, $y_{st} = \gamma T_{s} + \sum_{t=-k}^{0}{\beta_{t}} (T_{s} \times Pre_{t}) + \epsilon_{st}$. The $k$ in the lower limit is to show that it could generalize to any number of periods _before_ treatment. Is there a better way to subscript $\beta$ without confusing anyone? Or, would you recommend using an indicator function?

Comment: This seems clear to me, though personally I like the policy dummy D notation (the policy dummy is simply defined to be unity for groups and time periods subject to the
policy). I think you should also have a summation for the lambdas and a t subscript for them (each time dummy should have its own coefficient).

Comment: I denoted the $\lambda's$ as follows: $y_{st} = \gamma T_{s} + \sum_{t=-k}^{0}{\lambda_{t}} Pre_{t} + \sum_{t=-k}^{0}{\beta_{t}} (T_{s} \times Pre_{t}) + \epsilon_{st}.$ And, if I understand you correctly, you mean $D$ as in the result of the interaction ($s$*$t$)?

Comment: Yes to both questions.